# Facebook 3.0 issue with login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-sdk

I trying to understand how the facebook 3.0 SDK login proccess is working.
I walked through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) tutorial. every thing works fine, but how should I continue? Lets say that after loging in I want to get the users email or navigate to other activity. 
Where should I put my code in this case. I have this MainActivity code:

```
package com.shaleapp.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.shale.fragments.MainFragment;
import com.shaleapp.services.Init;
import com.shaleapp.shale.R;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private MainFragment mainFragment;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
          //ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this MainFragment code:

```
package com.shale.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.shaleapp.shale.R;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


}
```

I was trying to debug but couldn't find the point where the MainFragment returns the session or some other object to the MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the login when FB screens opens you it's going to `onActivityResult`.
Also when the session state changes you got it inside `Session.StatusCallback`. 
See all the values of `SessionState`
 and if you got an exception you also receive it there.
If you'll be more specific I'll be able to answer with more details.

Comment: So where should I put my code after the login process finishes?

Comment: At Session.StatusCallback when you pay attention to SessionState value.